# How to dynamically create variables names and dynamically assign them a functions to avoid repeating code in R?

Tags: r, lapply, assign

I want to make my code cleaner and more maintainable. For example, take the following `quantsList`list :

```
var <- "temperature"
quantsList <- list(
  q05 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.05, na.rm = TRUE)')
  q10 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.10, na.rm = TRUE)')
  q25 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.25, na.rm = TRUE)')
  q50 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.50, na.rm = TRUE)')
  q75 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.75, na.rm = TRUE)')
  q80 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.80, na.rm = TRUE)')
  q90 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.80, na.rm = TRUE)')
  q95 <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.80, na.rm = TRUE)')
)
```

This is a lot of repetition for creating this 5 elements list and I want to understand how to avoid such kind of bad coding, especially for lists that could be > 100 elements. My searches lead me to the `assign()` and is counterpart `get()` functions. But I can't really figure out how to properly "play" with these. For now, what I have :

```
# Attempt to create the list "quants" with dynamically named elements storing dynamically created functions

assignFuns <- function(q){
  quant = paste0("q",q)
  assign(quant, paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.',q,', na.rm = TRUE)'))
  return(get(quant))
}
quants <- list(05,10,25,50,75,80,90,95)
quantsList <- lapply(quants, assignFuns)
```

Doing so `quantList` contains the elements storing the quantiles functions but the list elements are unnamed.

I know I can simply name the elements of the list using :

```
names(quantsFuns) <- lapply(quants, function(x) paste0("q",x))
```

But this workflow seems me too convoluted and at the moment my combination of assign and get is useless.  I guess there should be a more efficient use of `assign()` or `get()`. Should I adapt my `assignFuns()` function so that it returns both the name and the corresponding function or should I proceed in a totally different way ?

Thanks for the insights and the help you could provide me regarding this problem

**Edit**

So according to @Roland, `assign()` is to avoid. So I'm simply using this code :

```
assignFuns <- function(q){
  quantFun <- paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=.',q,', na.rm = TRUE)')
  return(quantFun)
}
quants <- list(05,10,25,50,75,80,90,95)
quantsFuns <- lapply(quants, assignFuns)
names(quantsFuns) <- lapply(quants, function(x) paste0("q",x))
```

Comment: Do not assign this to separate symbols. Simply do something like this: `prob <- c(0.05, 0.1, 0.25, .5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8); 
prob <- sub("0.", ".", formatC(prob, digits = 2, format = "f"), fixed = TRUE);
paste0('quantile(',var,', probs=', prob, ', na.rm = TRUE)')`

Comment: `assign` is for very advanced stuff. You should never use it unless you are an expert working with environments in R. I haven't had a legitimate use for `assign` in my own work during the last 5+ years of using R.

Comment: I'm also suspicious why you are creating R commands as text. I hope you are not planning to eval/parse them.

Comment: As my comment shows, you do not need `lapply`. `paste0` is vectorized. Also, do not use a list if a vector is sufficient.

Comment: I use these R commands as texts that will be used in conjunction with a dplyr `summarise_( )` function.

Comment: There is almost certainly a better (more efficient and more idiomatic) way. This appears to be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

R doesn't work this way. It's not a macro language. And you really do not want to create a bunch of loose variables in the global environment. Instead create a named vector (or list).  The quantile function is designed to return a vector of quantiles.

```
t_probs <- c( 05,10,25,50,75,80,90,95)/100
temp_quants <- quantile( temperature, probs=t_probs)
# If you need them to be named then:
names(temp_quants) <- paste0( "Q_", t_probs)
```